# Why won't AngularJs recognise my {{ }} as an expression?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

For some reason, my curly brackets are printing what's inside of them (on the index.html file) and not redirecting to the $scope in my controller file.

Ok, so I'm trying to write create a quiz page using AngularJs and PHP as part of a school project. Right now I'm trying to get one of my controllers to work. (I'm currently following an online tutorial).

```
(function(){

    angular
      .module("LaBoa")
      .controller("listCtrl", [ListController]);

     function ListController($scope){
      // List Controller Logic

        $scope.dummyData = "hello world";
    }

  })();
```

This is what's written on the index.html page

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>La Boa- Quiz</h1>
      <h3>
        Weekly quiz! 
        <strong>La Boa- Quiz</strong>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="listCtrl"></div>
        {{dummyData}}

    </div>
```

Below is my whole index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="LaBoa">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Turtle Facts and Quiz</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap css and my own css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"

integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>La Boa- Quiz</h1>
      <h3>
        Weekly quiz! 
        <strong>La Boa- Quiz</strong>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="listCtrl">
          {{dummyData}}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- third party js -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Our application scripts -->
  <script scr="js/app.js"></script>
  <script scr="js/controllers/list.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

When I run this on a live-server it just shows "{{dummyData}}". I want it to say "hello world".

Comment: try to link the <body ng-app="LaBoa"> in the body tag

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck T_T

Comment: Can you provide a code of your whole html file?

Comment: I've added all the code in my html file, sorry for the late reply

Comment: Check the edited answer below

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it's still showing {{dummyData}}. Could it be due to the fact I'm using Visual studios to write this or because I have php my admin downloaded?

Comment: Did you try to just open the `index.html`? Are there any errors in the Google Chrome console?

Comment: yeah, I've tried opening it with both google chrome and windows explorer. Could it have something to do with the ways I arrange the folder. I have one big folder and then my file and js (javascript) folder. shoukd I put the index.html in my js folder or remove my js from a folder?

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have a few mistakes in strings when you load scripts at the bottom of html file (change `scr` on `src`).
Secondly, you didn't pass `$scope` into your controller.
Here you go...

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="LaBoa">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Turtle Facts and Quiz</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap css and my own css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"

integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>La Boa- Quiz</h1>
      <h3>
        Weekly quiz! 
        <strong>La Boa- Quiz</strong>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="listCtrl">
          {{dummyData}}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- third party js -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Our application scripts -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/list.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

js script

```
(function(){

    angular
      .module("LaBoa",[])
      .controller("listCtrl", ['$scope', ListController]);

     function ListController($scope){
      // List Controller Logic

        $scope.dummyData = "hello world";
    }

  })();
```

Comment: I tried changing it so that it's inside the div tag but It's still printing {{dummyData}}

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below plunker which may help you.

```
(function(){


    var myApp = angular.module('LaBoa',[]);

myApp.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.dummyData = "hello world";
}]);

  })();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/aU3KgU9ktFmPi4PPG1Te?p=preview

Comment: It's still coming up with "{{dummyData}}". I even tried replacing everything I wrote with your code but it still doesn't work. I don't know, perhaps it could be visual basics. I copied everything directly from the tutorial video but I'm getting errors when his runs fine.   I

Comment: did u include your script file within the html or try adding the javascript code within the script tag

Comment: whether you have any errors in the console while running

Comment: I don't think so, I'm not getting any erros when I try running it on a live server